# Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_' into field in views.py

Tags: python, django

In following tutorial, 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/

I did exactly the same as the tutorial instructed, create the template file in the polls/templates/polls/index.html:

```
polls/templates/polls/index.html¶
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And the views.py:
polls/views.py¶

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

When I start the server, and visit the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/, I got the following error:

```
FieldError at /polls/
Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text
Exception Location: /home/martin/anaconda3/envs/web/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in names_to_path, line 1389
Python Executable:  /home/martin/anaconda3/envs/web/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['/home/martin/nlp/web/web',
 '/home/martin/anaconda3/envs/web/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/martin/anaconda3/envs/web/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/martin/anaconda3/envs/web/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/martin/anaconda3/envs/web/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 3 Mar 2019 09:20:08 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /home/martin/nlp/web/web/polls/templates/polls/index.html, error at line 1

Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text
1   {% if latest_question_list %}
2       <ul>
3       {% for question in latest_question_list %}
4           <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
5       {% endfor %}
6       </ul>
7   {% else %}
8       <p>No polls are available.</p>
9   {% endif %}
10
```

I think it complains about this line:

```
latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

I run this line at the app's terminal, and found no problem. But when I run the app in the server, I always got this annoying issue.

Comment: Maybe you wrote `order_by('-pub_date'[:5])` instead of `order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` ?

Comment: What's the difference? exactly the same

Comment: Look carefully. The bracket after parenthesis or after string: `pub_date'[` vs `pub_date')[` .

Comment: Exactly right! Thank you

Comment: I post it as solution.

Comment: Also, I vote to close because this don't help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a kind of "typo" in your code.:

(I guess) **you wrote:**

> `Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date'[:5])`

That means *"all questions ordered descending by a field named `'pub_'`"* Because `'-pub_date'[:5]` is `'-pub_'`.

**You want to code:**

> `Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]`

That means *"the five latest questions"*.